# В приведённой фразе частицы НЕ/НИ взаимозаменяемы?

Tags: не-или-ни

> Я вполне понимаю, что все дороги ведут в суд, и мне это не по плечу -
>   ***ни по времени, ни по силам, ни по нервам***.

Первое не - в *не по плечу* - как бы вне рассмотрения.

А в трёх остальных случаях? Могут эти *ни* быть расширенным толкованием первого *не*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я вполне понимаю, что все дороги ведут в суд, и мне это не по плечу (мне это не подходит никак) — **ни по времени, ни по силам, ни по нервам.**

НИ здесь — усилительная частица в составе повторяющегося союза.

Смысл высказывания: Для меня это невозможно ни по времени, ни по силам, ни по нервам.

Answer (score 2):

Можно ли предположить, что автор хотел сказать: "мне это не по времени, мне это не по нервам"? Не думаю (так не выражаются). Значит, остается вариант с усилительной частицей 
**НИ**:

**Я вполне понимаю, что все дороги ведут в суд, и мне это не по плечу — ни по времени, ни по силам, ни по нервам.**